# Intellij menu and dialog fonts getting bold

Tags: intellij-idea

Not for the code editor but the IntelliJ menus and dialogs, fonts are getting bold.

My question would be:

- How can I make my IntelliJ IDE menu and dialog fonts not to be bold.

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screen shot "illustrating" your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just got the same problem after installing some package. This is a really late response I guess :)

Two options to resolve it:

1- Setting->Appearance: check Override default fonts by (not recommended), and change it to your liking.

2- I tried this command to remove this font, because my thunderbird was also effected:

sudo apt-get remove fonts-unfonts-core

cheers.